# Converting a .FLV into a .AVI / .MP4

Tags: avi, mp4, flv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you convert FLV file format to a format that Picasa recognizes (e.g. AVI, MPEG, WMV)?](https://superuser.com/questions/94106/how-do-you-convert-flv-file-format-to-a-format-that-picasa-recognizes-e-g-avi)

Well i've been looking around google for hours trying to find a way on how to convert a FLV (Flash Video File) into an .AVI or .MP4 Video. There's something that let's me do this type of converts?

Comment: please add more details. what is your operating system? what type of conversion are you looking for (online or local)?

Comment: See also: [Software to convert avi files to any other type of files](http://superuser.com/questions/85099/software-to-convert-avi-files-to-any-other-type-of-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Get the latest FFmpeg build from [Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
2. Extract the executable to a searchable path (e.g. %windir%)
3. Use the following at the command prompt

   ```
   ffmpeg -i "your flv file.flv" "your avi file.avi"
   ```

---

There are a lot of other things that you can do with FFmpeg, for example trying to copy the video and audio streams instead of re-encoding the FLV file (which would result in noticeable quality loss):

```
ffmpeg -i "your flv file.flv" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "your avi file.avi"
```

This may or may not work depending on the codecs used in the original file.

Comment: Well, a "lot of other things" would for example include just changing the container. The syntax you gave will re-encode the video without any advanced settings, therefore drastically reducing the quality.

Comment: I would doubt the "drastically" bit. Depends a lot on the content itself.

Comment: I've had very bad experiences. You're right though, as always, it depends :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something quick you can use:

http://www.mediaconverter.org/

or

http://www.zamzar.com/

or you can google it:

https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=convert+videos+online

You don't have to download any programs for these, you just upload your video online and download the converted file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Pazera FLV to Avi converter](http://www.pazera-software.com/products/flv-to-avi-converter/)